# Need to Bridge Network Port from local machine to Vagrant VM

Tags: networking, vagrant, vagrantfile

On my development machine, I can see the following DHCP traffic on eth1 port:

```
sudo tcpdump -i eth1
tcpdump: verbose output suppressed, use -v or -vv for full protocol decode
listening on eth1, link-type EN10MB (Ethernet), capture size 262144 bytes
09:51:58.785056 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, 
Request from 00:06:31:c7:1e:23 (oui Unknown), length 315
09:51:58.785384 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, 
Request from 00:06:31:c7:1e:23 (oui Unknown), length 315
09:51:59.786677 IP 0.0.0.0.bootpc > 255.255.255.255.bootps: BOOTP/DHCP, 
Request from 00:06:31:c7:1e:23 (oui Unknown), length 315
```

I want to see this same traffic in my Vagrant VM. So I want to bridge the eth1 port on my development machine to some port on my Vagrant VM. I also want to be able to send network traffic from my Vagrant VM back onto the eth1.

Using the answer in the following question: 
https://superuser.com/questions/752954/need-to-do-bridged-adapter-only-in-vagrant-no-nat

I added this to my Vagrantfile:

```
config.vm.provision "shell",
run: "always",
inline: "route -A inet6 add deault gw fc00::1 eth1"
```

But I don't really know what this does, except that it seems to only route ipv6 traffic? Could someone help explain how to bridge eth1 to a port on my Vagrant VM?

I also tried the following in my Vagrantfile:

```
Vagrant::Config.run do |config|
  config.vm.network :bridged
end
```

yet after I do vagrant up again, I still don't see any port (using ifconfig) in my VM that has the DHCP traffic.

Answer (score 0):

After reading up on Vagrant, I found a solution that worked for me.

Firstly, I ran the following command on my host machine:
`sudo ip route add 192.168.1.0/24 dev eth1`

My understanding is that this routes traffic from eth1 physical port to 192.168.1.0 IP address.

Then, in my Vagrantfile I added the following under `Vagrant.configure(2) do |config|`:
`config.vm.network “public_network”, bridge: “eth1”
 config.vm.network “public_network”, ip: “192.168.1.0”`

After doing vagrant destroy and vagrant up, I now see a new port in my vagrant VM (enp0s8), that if I do tcpdump on I see the DHCP traffic (and other traffic) that is arriving on my eth1 port on my host machine.

Not sure if this is the best solution, as I am still very new to vagrant and VirtualBox, but this worked for me.